# Open image (InternalStorage) with android default application using FileProvider

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I have a picture stored in my internal application storage, and I want to open it with android default application (gallery or any other).

So I'm using a FileProvider, my code works fine on android 4.3, but on some versions (2.3.6 for example), it doesn't work, the application open itself but then blackscreen, nothing.
My app needs to be API-10 compatible

I read many topics relating this problem, nothing seems to fix it. The code is probably not wrong since it works on 4.3...
Any thought?

My code to launch the activity :

```
File file = getMyFile();
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), <full-path-to-my-activity>, file);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with");

startActivity(intent);
```

in my manifest :

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="<full-path-to-my-activity>"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider"/>
</provider>
```

my provider.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<files-path
    name="pictures"
    path=""/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Most likely, the problem is in the other app, not yours. Many Android developers have not been handling `content://` `Uri` values very well: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html

Comment: Well the app I tried it with, is the official Android gallery application. My guess is it should work no ?

Comment: "My guess is it should work no ? " -- I would not assume that, particularly going back that far. Does LogCat show any error messages, perhaps coming from the Gallery?

Comment: Nope, nothing from the LogCat.

Comment: What sort of image is this (PNG? JPEG?), and where are you running this code (emulator? specific device model?). I can see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The image is a jpeg, I tried on a Galaxy S (I9000) with android 2.3.6 and it didn't work. (Worked fine on my Oppo find 7A with 4.3).

Comment: Try the emulator. The problem may be specific to Samsung's Gallery replacement.

Comment: It could be, I tried on a galaxy trend too, it didn't work with gallery application, but worked with "Picture" application. Trying now with genymotion

Comment: Ok, it worked on a Nexus S with the original gallery. I think we can assume indeed that samsung apps is the problem, I'll have to check if it concerns every versions or if it has been fixed since. Thanks anyway ! Now I'll check if it's possible to do nothing if no other app than the samsung one is available.

Comment: FYI : On some samsug devices (galaxy s2 with 2.3.7), the code above crashes the application with a nullpointer in FileProvider methods.

Comment: It crashes *your* app? That's interesting. You might want to either edit this question, or ask a fresh one, where you include the stack trace for that crash.